# C remove dot at endline

Tags: c

How can I remove the dot at the end of a line in C? This is my current code but it eliminates all dots, even in the middle of the word.

```
  char *pc;
  pc = strtok(acData, " .\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings are of this format: `word word word.`
Then `pc[strlen(pc) - 1]` corresponds to `\0` and `pc[strlen(pc) - 2]` to the `.`, so by doing 
    `pc[strlen(pc) - 2] = '\0';` it will remove the `.`.

If your strings contain `\n` then you should do `pc[strlen(pc) - 3] = '\0';`.

Comment: Note that if you need to do lots of string operations you should probably store `strlen` somewhere rather than calling it inline like this. It's O(N) rather than O(1).

Comment: i do call it inline like this and i do lots of string operations.
if it cause performance problem,how should i use it then?im quite new to C

Comment: @towkan you can run it and see how fast it is. Are your strings too long? Could you give us an example of your code, you just remove the `.` or do you do also other edits to the string?

Comment: input : "://pqre.mimos.my/perfunleashedconf."
 output : ://erqp.somim.ym/fnocdehsealnufrep
 thats what im trying to get.read the input from a file,and convert it to output format.and trying to put a lots of line,mybe hundreds.my priority is the performance.im just playing with C.trying to understand everything

Answer (score 0):

call strpbrk() for matching eol character you want. and set \0

```
char* ptr = strpbrk(pc, "\r\n.");
if (ptr) *ptr = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick I often use for stripping off newlines at the end of user-input strings.

```
if ((ln = strlen (str)) > 0)
    if (str[ln-1] == '\n')
        str[ln-1] = '\0';
```

You can *exactly* the same method to get rid of the `.` at the end of a string:

```
size_t ln;
char str[] = "Hello there.";
if ((ln = strlen (str)) > 0)
    if (str[ln-1] == '.')
        str[ln-1] = '\0';
```

If the input format has a newline on the end as well, you'll need a slight modification:

```
size_t ln;
char str[] = "Hello there.\n";
if ((ln = strlen (str)) > 1)
    if (str[ln-2] == '.')
        strcpy (&(str[ln-2]), "\n");
```

Comment: `s/int/size_t/g` You ought to know better, pax... ;)

Comment: @Chris, you may consider me suitably chastised :-)